# Set default frontpage to Front Page view

Tags: views

I've setted the Default front page to the View Front Page, but when I go to www.mydomain.com the page don't redirects to www.mydomain.com/frontpage.

When I go and write www.mydomain.com/frontpage the Front Page view is displayed.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set it here:

http://www.DOMAIN.com/admin/config/system/site-information

You set the "Default Front Page Link" there.

When you hit your root (/) url, it will not "redirect" to that custom url you set, but it will auto render the url you inputted.

If you want to do a true redirect when hitting the frontpage you might have to do it via the .htaccess file as I'm not sure if there is module that can do a redirect from the frontpage.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That was exact what I did. I expected don't "really" redirect to /frontpage but rather only render /frontpage as you mentioned. But the page is not rendered, although www.mydomain.com/frontpage is working.